# How can I insert JSON value to mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I can't insert json value into table.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const user = {};

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',`enter code here`
    password:'homi98',
    database:'homi',
    port:'3306',
});

user.path = "C:\\nodejsWorkspace\\Mysql";
user.date = "20190805";
user.weather = "sunny";
user.temp = 31;
user.day = "월요일";

console.log(user);

connection.connect();


connection.query('insert into homi01 (path,date,weather,temp,day) values (.$user[\'path\'].,\'20190805\',\'sunny\',31,\'월요일\'); '
    ,(error, results, fields) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(results);
    });

connection.end();
```

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '.$user['path'].,'20190805','sunny',31,'월요일')' at
>   line 1
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError

Answer (score -1):

The query is not syntactically incorrect due to the way you are extracting values from your object. Use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make this kind of concatenation simpler.

```
connection.query(`insert into homi01 (path, date, weather, temp, day) values ( "${user.path}", 20190805, "sunny", 31, "월요일"`
    ,(error, results, fields) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Edit:

If you have problems using Template Strings, here is how your query will be logged:

```js
var user = {path: 'c:\\temp'}

console.log(`insert into homi01 (path, date, weather, temp, day) values ( "${user.path}", 20190805, "sunny", 31, "월요일"`);
```

Comment: Any reason why this solution doesn't work? I can learn if any :)

Comment: I want to extract the character from json and put the value. But that way, $ {user.path} literally goes into the table.



I want to make table like 
number   |   path   |     date    | weather | temp | day |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1         | c://~~~ | 190805   |  strom    |    29  | Mon

Comment: `"${user.path}"` will output "c://~~~" - because it is inside a template string.

Comment: Put it in the query in the way you have told me, it prints like ${user.path} .

Comment: Looks like you are not using it correctly. See the edited part and how it prints correctly.